# How to change ```<h2>``` to ```<h2 data-splitting>```?

Tags: css, javascript

**How to change the heading tags `<h1>` to `<h1 data-splitting>` and `<h2>` to `<h2 data-splitting>` and `<h3>` to `<h3 data-splitting>` and `<h4>` to `<h4 data-splitting>` in WordPress?**

How can I change them on all pages through hard coding or by change through JS/JQuery?

For hard coding, where should I look at, on theme files, or is it coded into the WordPress itself?

There are ID’s and classes such as `<div id="nav">` and `<div class="sidebar-box">` but what is the above type is called as? Is it same as `<h2>` + `<data-splitting>`?

This is required to add some animation effect to the headings - [View on Codepen](https://codepen.io/shshaw/pen/YOPqLb)

Now how can I change heading tags?

I added this to the WordPress fuctions.php:-

```
 function enqueue_my_custom_script() {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'hjs', 'https://example.com/h.js', false );
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_my_custom_script' );
```

The h.js has the following code:-

```
$('document').ready(function() {

    $('h1, h2, h3, h4').attr('data-splitting', '');

});
```

But this doesn't add the script to the head.

I even added it manually as `<script async src="https://example.com/h.js">` but it does **not** gets show up in the head

If I add any other script manually like `<script async src="https://example.com/a.js">` it **does** gets added.

I even tried to add the JS as inline in the head, now the script **does shows up in the head section as inline JS** but doesn't change the `<h1>` to `<h1 data-splitting>` and `<h2>` to `<h2 data-splitting>`.

```
<script>
$('document').ready(function() {

    $('h1, h2, h3, h4').attr('data-splitting', '');

});
</script
```

or as

```
<script>
jQuery.noConflict()(function($) {
    $('document').ready(function() {

        $('h1, h2, h3, h4').attr('data-splitting', '');

    });
});
</script>
```

Now the script is present in the head as inline JS but it does change the heading tags.

I can't make it to work. Is there no way to hard code into the WordPress?

Comment: why do you need to add `data-splitting` to every heading? If you can load the javascript then I'm not sure what kind of help you need that needs WordPress expertise, are you sure this isn't a vanilla javascript question better asked on stackoverflow?

Answer (score 1):

The headings will be defined in many different places, mostly in the theme and in the page content. So using JS as you have will be the most reliable approach.

A few things to note about enqueuing scripts:

- As your script uses jQuery, you need to pass jQuery as a dependency to make sure it loads after jQuery does so that it's actually defined when it tries to run. `wp_enqueue_script( 'hjs', 'https://example.com/h.js', array( 'jquery' ) );`
- jQuery in WordPress runs in noConflict mode, so you can't just use the `$` variable for the jQuery object. [This article](https://digwp.com/2011/09/using-instead-of-jquery-in-wordpress/) has more information.

Now all that aside, from looking at the codepen I'm not sure any of this is nessecary. For the ScrollOut settings it is targetting the `data-splitting` attribute like so:

```
ScrollOut({
   targets: '[data-splitting]'
});
```

However, you can change that to instead just target all the headings instead of trying to add that data attribute to the headings first, like so:

```
ScrollOut({
   targets: 'h1,h2,h3,h4'
});
```

And also updating what the Splitting.js target is, as per the [options](https://splitting.js.org/guide.html#options) (the `data-splitting` attribute is just the default)

```
Splitting({
  target: 'h1,h2,h3,h4'
});
```

[Working demo without data attributes](https://codepen.io/cameronjonesweb/pen/JjLRXMw)

Comment: There is a problem with changing the targets from `targets: '[data-splitting]'` to `targets: 'h1,h2,h3,h4'`. The following files which are being added for the text effect has reference to the old `'[data-splitting]'` - <script src="https://unpkg.com/splitting/dist/splitting.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/scroll-out/dist/scroll-out.js"></script> https://unpkg.com/splitting/dist/splitting.css How to change the old reference to just heading tags?

Comment: @CrazyJack You can instantiate `Splitting` with options to change the target as well. I've updated my answer with more details